# Could not get unknown property 'arm64-v8a' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I'm following the guide on [Android ABIS doc](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) and it said to use 'arm64-v8a' to meet with Play Store 64 bit requirements.

I added my `so` files under `libs/arm64-v8a/` And then I added `abiFilter` as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
  ...

  ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'  'arm64-v8a'
      }

  ...
}
```

When I build the project, I keep getting error

```
Could not get unknown property 'arm64-v8a' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.6 rc-03, Gradle version 5.6.4, with ndk version of 21.0.6113669.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I forgot to add "," between `'armeabi'` and `'arm64-v8a'`

This is working now

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
      }
```